# Why?$\int_0^1\int_{u(t)}^{u(t)+w(t)} f(t,v(t)) dv dt = \int_0^1 f(t,u(t)+\theta w(t))w(t) dt; ~~\theta\in[0,1] $

Tags: integration, analysis, functional-analysis

why: $$\int_0^1\int_{u(t)}^{u(t)+w(t)} f(t,v(t)) dv dt = \int_0^1 f(t,u(t)+\theta w(t))w(t) dt; ~~\theta\in[0,1] $$

how to get this ?

Please help me

Thank you.

Comment: The statement is clearly not true.  Consider $w(t) = 0$ and $f(t, r) = 1$.  Your equation evaluates to $0 = 1$ in that case.

Comment: $w(t)\neq 0$ , how to do ?

Comment: It's still true that if $f=1$ then the right side is $1$ and the left side is $\int_0^1w(t)\,dt$.

Comment: ok but if i only have that $\int_0^1\int_{u(t)}^{u(t)+w(t)} f(t,v(t)) dv dt$ how to find $ \int_0^1 f(t,u(t)+\theta w(t)) dt; ~~\theta\in[0,1]$ ??

Comment: I'm guessing your homework problem is more than just an equation.  Until you are ready to consider the extra information you won't be able to solve this problem and no one will be able to help you.

Comment: it's not a homework, it's juste that i study a paper and i dont understand this stepbut there is no more information

Comment: Do you have a link to the paper? There's no way to find the 2nd integral, if al you know is the value of the 1st integral.

Comment: I HAVE IT ON PDF

Comment: Does the paper have an author and a title? You are not making it easy for anyone to help you.

Comment: Existence and multiplicity of solutions of a kind of
fourth-order boundary value problem
Fuyi Li, Qi Zhang, Zhanping Liang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^1 dt \int_{u(t)}^{u(t)+w(t)}  dv f(t,v)
=\int_0^1 dt \int_{0}^{1}  (w(t)d\theta) f(t,u(t) +\theta w(t))\\
=\int_{0}^{1}  d\theta \int_0^1 w(t)dt  f(t,u(t) +\theta w(t))
$$
Now using the Mean value theorem for integrals:

$$
\exists \theta_0\in(0,1) \int_0^1 dt \int_{u(t)}^{u(t)+w(t)}  dv f(t,v)
=\int_0^1 w(t)dt  f(t,u(t) +\theta_0 w(t))
$$

Comment: we can use only the mean value theorem ?, and why $\int_0^1 \int_{u(t)}^{u(t)+w(t)} f(t,v) dv dt =\int_0^1 dt\int_{u(t)}^{u(t)+w(t)} dv f(t,v)$ ?

Comment: I assume we can use it, in the context of the article. I only explain one way to go to the desired conclusion.

Comment: and why $\int_0^1 \int_{u(t)}^{u(t)+w(t)} f(t,v) dv dt =\int_0^1 dt\int_{u(t)}^{u(t)+w(t)} dv f(t,v)$ please

Comment: and $$\int_0^1 dt \int_{u(t)}^{u(t)+w(t)}  dv f(t,v)
=\int_0^1 dt \int_{0}^{1}  (w(t)d\theta) f(t,u(t) +\theta w(t))\\
=\int_{0}^{1}  d\theta \int_0^1 w(t)dt  f(t,u(t) +\theta w(t))
$$ dont give the desired conclusion !

Comment: for the first one: ensure you can use the Fubini theorem.

Comment: for the second one: yes, then use the mean value theorem!

Comment: so the mean value theorem is important here

Comment: of course, it makes things work here.